# Can we omit "as possible" in "as many X as possible" in informal speech?

Tags: informal-language

I just got out of a photo studio to get some pictures for my passport and I told the photographer "Do you have a ten, I am trying to collect as many ten." It sounded more natural to end with "ten" than with "as possible", but on second thought I don't think this is even correct in informal speech. What's your opinion on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "a ten"? Are you collecting ten-dollar bills?

Comment: You can also say "I'm trying to collect tens." When you're collecting things, it's understood that you want as many as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that sentence is not grammatical. You should have said "Do you have a ten? I am trying to collect as many **tens as possible**." When you use the phrase "**as X ...**" you have to have something to compare it to, so it's "**as X as Y**".

Comment: See this explanation of similes, which is what this type of construction is called: https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/similes.html

Comment: And note that you need to use the plural, "tens". You can't use "many" with a singular noun.